# Why is definition of vbtab is vbtab?

Tags: vb.net

My daughter asked me what is vbtab. I told her, just right click and this is what we saw

```
    '
    ' Summary:
    '     Represents a tab character for print and display functions.
    Public Const vbTab As String = vbTab
```

Wait a minute. That looks like circular definition.

Why vb.net define it that way? What am I missing here?

Some answers claim that it's defined as chrw(7) or whatever.

Here is the screenshot of what I see

[image]

Looks like the definition that I got in visual studio when right clicking and go to definition, and the definition that I got in https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic/Microsoft/VisualBasic/Constants.cs,70a0e4b6cb134fb0 and https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/79ae74f5ca5c8a6fe3a48935e85bd7374959c570/src/libraries/Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core/src/Microsoft/VisualBasic/Constants.vb are all different.

In that case this question should also ask why the differences?

Comment: Perhaps this might clarify it a bit https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic/Microsoft/VisualBasic/Constants.cs,70a0e4b6cb134fb0

The value is indeed the tab character, which when displayed as VB.NET code is helpfully shown as it string representative.

Comment: Or here's the actual code used by VB.NET https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/79ae74f5ca5c8a6fe3a48935e85bd7374959c570/src/libraries/Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core/src/Microsoft/VisualBasic/Constants.vb

Comment: Keep in mind that you're not looking at source code, this is output generated by a decompiler.  Which takes the IL definition in the reference assembly and translates it back to the equivalent language definition.  The IDE has decompilers for C# and VB.NET.  Fairly sophisticated, but for one you never get to see the source code of a method.  But sophisticated enough to know that ChrW(9) has a more succinct expression in VB.NET.